# Filter DateTime in DataView does not filter minutes and second

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, dataview

I have the following code (a DataView that filtered by DateTime):

```
dv = new DataView(
        dataTable1,
        "DateTime >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime("7/5/2011 9:21:00 AM") + "'",
        "ID ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

My datatable1 consist of the following data in the DateTime column:

- A:  "7/5/2011 9:20:59 AM"
- B:  "7/5/2011 9:21:00 AM"
- C:  "7/5/2011 9:21:01 AM"
- D:  "7/5/2011 9:22:00 AM"

Supposedly, only **A** should get filtered. 
But my code has **A**, **B** and **C** filtered as well, and only returns **D**.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enclosing the date string with `#`.  For example:

```
dv = new DataView(
        dataTable1,
        "DateTime >= #" + Convert.ToDateTime("7/5/2011 9:21:00 AM") + "#",
        "ID ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Comment: tried yours and I get "The expression contains invalid date constant '#'."

Comment: sorry... how about if you exclude the single quotes.

dv = new DataView( dataTable1, "DateTime >= #" + Convert.ToDateTime("7/5/2011 9:21:00 AM") + "#", "ID ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
dv = new DataView(
    dataTable1,
    "CONVERT(DateTime, System.DateTime) >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime("7/5/2011 9:21:00 AM") + "'",
    "ID ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Comment: @c0deNinja, tried yours and I get "The expression contains invalid date constant '#'."

Comment: @KMC I tried  your example, and the result turns out even with or without CONVERT (like I said), only A was filtered. So I am thinking about your row state, may be they were marked as deleted. Please double check!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `convert.todatetime`.

You can try this

```
String date1 =String.Empty ;
date1 = "7/5/2011 9:21:00 AM";
dv = new DataView(dataTable1,"DateTime >= #" + date1 + "#", "ID ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```